# change the position of image on click

Tags: javascript, html

```
   <html>
   <head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function changepic()
   {
   document.getElementById("demo").style.top=2000;  
   }
   </script>
    </head>
   <body>

 <h1>My First Web Page</h1>
  <div id="demo">
  <img src="./omna.jpg"  style="position:absolute; left: 400; top: 100; width: 200;      height: 200;"/>
  </div>
  <button type="button" onclick="changepic()">change pic</button>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Why im unable to change the position of picture whats going wrong ?

```
<img id="demo"> ' google says it works
```

I dont know but the above html page isnt working I wanted to change the position of an image when I click the button, please help me with these. Im using google chrome

```
<img onclick="somefunc()"> can I set function onclick to image also? right?
```

But its not working please help me with the html Code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set the `top` of an element with the id `demo`, which is a `<div>`. I assume that div doesn't have `position:absolute` set on it so won't move anywhere, and I guess you want the `<img>` to move and and not the `<div>` anyway. If you remove the id from the `<div>` and add it to the `<img>` (like in your second piece of code above) you shouldn't have any problems. This code should work:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function changepic()
{
 document.getElementById("demo").style.top=2000 + "px";  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>My First Web Page</h1>
<div>
<img id="demp" src="./omna.jpg"  style="position:absolute; left: 400; top: 100; width: 200;      height: 200;"/>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="changepic()">change pic</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You setting the inline style of the *image* and then setting the `top` of the div. Either do one or the other. Or better still just remove the div, add an `id` to your  and set it's style.

```
<img id="image" src="./omna.jpg"  style="position:absolute; left: 400; top: 100; width: 200; height: 200;" />

document.getElementById("image").style.top=2000;
```